# Get IP from externally created load balancers with terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I'm working on a terraform module to create a GKE cluster. The same module invokes a provisioner that performs a `helm install` of an application.

The helm chart creates load balancer. The load balancer is not know to the terraform module so that the assigned IP address can't be reused in the module.

**Question:**

How can I use the IP of the load balancer to create DNS entries and get certificates?

I think this is no exotic use case but I haven't yet found a decent way to achieve this.

Comment: [cert-manager](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager) might help

Comment: That might be true for the certificate. But first you need a DNS entry.

Comment: Afaik cert-manger can add DNS entry as well.

Comment: Only TXT records for validation purposes.

Comment: have you had a look at external-dns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct answer to this question is:

The data source of the [kubernetes_service](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/d/service.html).

The concept of [Data Source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/data-sources.html) is exactly solving the issue here.

Appart from the above kubernetes_service data source I could have also ran a shell script with kubectl querying the ip and use [External Data Source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/external/data_source.html) as a generic solution.

From there I can use the IP address in a dns provider and in an acme provider to create dns entries and certificates.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the cloud provider did not expose the [`load_balancer_ip`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/data-sources/service#load_balancer_ip) so I had to create the service as `type: NodePort` via helm and created the loadbalancer manually directly via terraform.

I guess this is a valid workaround in cases where [the accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57930126/1521347) doesn't work due to this specific reason and the helm chart provides means to deploy the service as a different `type`.

Comment: Hi MoRe, I am also trying to get this working with a type NodePort service and creating a load balancer myself, but when I do this I get 404 on each route. I have created a topic for this, do you have an idea how to fix this maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75420451/404-with-traefik-ingress-controller-using-nodeport-service-type